# how to install packages o python?

Tags: python

Mac OSX 10.6.8 Python 2.7

Hi guys,

I just recently started programming with Python using the "Think Python" by Allen Downey. In Chapter 4, the first case study, he recommends to install a package called swampy...so basically I´m stuck here. For trouble shooting Downey recommends:

- import swampy.TurtleWorld -> doesnt work
- pip install swampy -> command not found(Could`t also install pip)

After typing

- sudo python setup.py install

I get

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Then I unzip the package swampy and thought to drag&drop it into the appropriate directory, however my directory ends with `System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources` here I have 3 objects "`English.Iproj`" "`inof.plist`" and "`Python`"

Does anybody have some suggestions how to install that package?

THX a lot

Answer (score 2):

you shall do:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install swampy
```

Comment: sudo easy_install pip
python version 2.7.6 can't run /usr/bin/easy_install.  Try the alternative(s):

/usr/bin/easy_install-2.5 (uses python 2.5)
/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 (uses python 2.6)

Run "man python" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.

Comment: Dont know how to interpret that

Comment: that means that you break your vanilla python 2.7 installation somehow. You may install pip using `sudo easy_install-2.6 pip`, and then run your code using the old python using `python2.6`, and/or fix your python 2.7 installation.

Comment: And how would I fix the 2.7 installation? Is there a general way? Should I uninstall something athe the beginning? I basically followed that page when istalling python 2.7 http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the directory where setup.py is located.
2. Enter into console next: sudo python setup.py install

Or use easy_install Or pip.

Comment: Users/Desktop/swampy-2.1.7 that is the directory... do i have to type sudo python Users/Desktop/swampy-2.1.7/setup.py install ?

Comment: Try it. Should work. And change path to /Users...